# Cannot find module '@foundry/ontology-api' or its corresponding type declarations

Tags: typescript, palantir-foundry

When opening a branch in a Typescript repository, the following error appears against one of the modules @foundry/ontology-api in the import statement:

> [typescript] Cannot find module '@foundry/ontology-api' or its
> corresponding type declarations

This appears after the Code Assist feature has loaded successfully.

Answer (score 1):

There appears to be a timing issue between the environment fully loading all the modules and Code Assist recognising them.
My often used workaround is to allow Code Assist to finish loading and then refresh the browser (i.e. F5). After the second attempt at loading Code Assist completes, the modules are no longer flagged as unrecognised.

Answer (score 0):

```
 {
  "name": "my-functions",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "My Functions",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
  "dependencies": {
    "@foundry/functions-api": "0.54.0",
    "@foundry/functions-typescript-runtime-internal-api": "0.33.0",
    "@foundry/functions-utils": "0.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@foundry/functions-typescript-authoring-dev": "0.44.0",
    "@foundry/functions-typescript-ontology-code-generator": "0.45.0",
    "@foundry/functions-typescript-discovery": "0.30.0",
    "@foundry/functions-typescript-object-set-base": "1.31.0",
    "@foundry/functions-testing-lib": "0.16.0",
    "jest": "27.5.1",
    "ts-jest": "27.1.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "../gradlew build",
    "check": "../gradlew check",
    "test": "../gradlew test",
    "jest": "jest"
  },
  "license": "UNLICENSED"
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).